# Find maximum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{24}i a_i$ for integers $|a_i|\le i, \forall i $ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{24} a_i = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

> Let $a_{i}(i=1,2,\cdots,24)$ be integers,and such $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{24}=0$,and $|a_{i}|\le i,i=1,2,\cdots,24$.Find the maximum of the value
> $$a_{1}+2a_{2}+3a_{3}+\cdots+24a_{24}$$

It seem use Ablel indentity to solve it?But I try some methods can't to solve it

Comment: You can use the fact that $a1+a2+.......+a24=0$ and replace the value of this equation in this equation $a1+2a2+3a3+.....+24a24$

Comment: At worst, this is a linear program; maximize the linear functional $\langle1,2,\ldots,24\rangle\cdot\vec{a}$ subject to the various linear equalities and inequalities.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki does LPP will really help for integer solution? (just curious!)

Comment: @MANMAID: Of course not every linear program with integer coefficients and constraints will give an integer solution.  But when one does it solves the ILP, and I suspect that is true here.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum is $1432$, whether or not integrality is imposed.  First consider the following solution:
$$a_i^* =
\begin{cases}
-i &\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,16\}$}\\
-11 &\text{for $i=17$} \\
i &\text{for $i\in\{18,\dots,24\}$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $a_i^* \le |i|$, and it is easy to check that $\sum_i a_i^* = 0$ and $\sum_i i a_i^* = 1432$, yielding a lower bound on the maximum.

To prove the upper bound, multiply constraints $-a_i \le i$ by $17-i$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,16\}$, $a_i \le i$ by $i-17$ for $i\in\{18,\dots,24\}$, and $\sum_i a_i = 0$ by $17$, and add these up, yielding
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{16} (17-i)(-a_i)
+\sum_{i=18}^{24} (i-17)a_i
+\sum_{i=1}^{24} 17 a_i
\le
\sum_{i=1}^{16} (17-i)i
+\sum_{i=18}^{24} (i-17)i
+0,
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{24} i a_i
\le
1432.
$$
The "magic" multipliers are the linear programming dual variables.

Comment: Very nice. Actually, I have done LP by relaxing the integrality constraint which outputs integral solutions. Also, I have a proof based on this and Mark Bennet's nice answer. But your 'magic" multipliers are very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Some observations, assuming the constraint is observed.

Suppose $i\gt j$ and $|a_i|\lt i, |a_j|\lt j$, then we get a greater sum by using $a_i+1, a_j-1$ which increases the total by $i-j\gt 0$.

Also with $a_i\lt i, a_j=j$ we can do the same.

From this we note that at most one of the $a_i$ is not on the limit, because with a pair off the limit we can always increase the sum. The second observation tells us that if there is one off the limit, everything below it is on the negative limit (because if there were something below on the positive limit, we could increase the sum).

From this we build from all zeros, to make $a_{24}=24$ with $a_1=-1, a_2=-2, a_3=-3, a_4=-4, a_5=-5, a_6=-6, a_7=-3$, then we make $a_{23}=23$ by decreasing $a_j$ for the smallest $j$ we can - and keep going until we can do no more.